# Node.js trouble

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get started with node.js, but I'm in no way an advanced programmer.
And I've never used cmd other than to check my ip.

My problem is I don't know where to save the files, and how to run them from cmd with node. The tutorials I've found seem to assume I should know all this without explaining it, and jumps straight to the code.

So, how do I actually run something in node? This is what I've done sofar:

1. Downloaded the windows installer from nodejs.org.
2. Installed nodejs in the default directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs.
3. Made sure I have Python and Microsoft Visual Studio.

And this is where I'm stuck, how do I test this?

1. It wont let me save files in the nodejs directory (even as
   administrator). Where do I save my files?
2. What would be the correct command and path in cmd to start node and run my files?

Comment: If you installed Node correctly, typing `node` in your CMD should work?!

Comment: Typing node doesn't do anything, but it doesn't give me an error either. Should be working right?

Comment: That can´t be true. It has to be either working or failing. It is probably working without you knowing. Does it jump to the next line with a `>` as prefix?

Comment: Typing `node` by itself at a `cmd` prompt drops you into the interactive node interpreter at a `>` prompt, as Amberlamps mentions.

Comment: Yes, by nothing I meant I get >, when I run my helloworld.js (on desktop) with node helloworld.js I get "..." instead of ">". It's running I guess?

Comment: Probably. Clear your helloworld.js, put just `console.log("Hello World!");` in it and run it again.

Comment: @Amberlamps That's exactly what I have in it, but I just get the dots on a new line. It's in cmd it's supposed to print hello world right?

Comment: If you see `...` that means you're still in the interactive interpreter.  You need to break out of it with Ctrl+D and try again from the `cmd` prompt.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Did CTRL+D and it set the path to C:\Windows\System32> and tries to look for helloworld.js in that directory. Just to try I puth the file there and it can't find it. This is like rocket science.

Comment: "it" is not setting the path to anything. Navigate to your directory and type `node helloworld.js`

Comment: How do I navigate to a directory? :P As I said I only know how to check my ip in cmd, complete noob.

Comment: Type `cd [pathtoyourdirectory]`. For example: `cd c:/Users/Hustlerinc/Desktop`

Comment: `cd %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Desktop`

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for all the help, never been this happy to see Hello World.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save your files wherever you want and run them from the `cmd` prompt as `node yourfile.js`.